# Magento 2 : Form Component changes through component are ignored

Tags: magento2, event-observer, knockoutjs, component

I think there is a "changed" event somewhere that needs to be called, but I don't know what element or component, here is my code:

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'uiRegistry', 'underscore'], function($, uiRegistry, _) {
    "use strict";

    // Note: there is a function here that makes sure everything is loaded, then move on to pointers.

    // customer components pointers
    var websiteId = uiRegistry.get('customer_form.areas.customer.customer.website_id');
    var groupId = uiRegistry.get('customer_form.areas.customer.customer.container_group.group_id');
    var storeId = uiRegistry.get('customer_form.areas.customer.customer.sendemail_store_id'); // store_id

    // address components pointers
    var addressCollection = uiRegistry.get('customer_form.areas.address.address.address_collection');

    // method A)
    // Example setter / getter thru component
    groupId.value('3');
    alert(groupId.value());

    // method B)
    // Example setter / getter thru DOM / jQuery
    $('#' + groupId.uid).val('3');
    $('#' + groupId.uid).val();

});
```

In method A the form data should get updated properly, bu it won't.
I need to make changes to the form (fieldset) FOR the user automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, gotta use **set** method for certain property changes.
Examples:

```
// wrong way:
component.value('somevalue');
component.required(true);

// correct way. (it will handle all event emitters)
component.set('value', 'somevalue');
component.set('required', true);
```